# Video not playing after deployment on vercel but locally it is running

Tags: reactjs, video, html5-video, vercel

I am using a custom video player in react and it is working fine on localhost but when i deploy it on vercel it is not working. I need help about this and idk what to do, vimeo external links will work i guess but those are paid and i need a free solution.

Here's the GitHub repo I'm using for custom video player

https://github.com/PiotrBerebecki/custom-video-player-react

Deployed link of above repo: https://custom-video-player-react.herokuapp.com/

And below is my vercel link

https://saderino-dapp-plnhfmbis-blockeyfi.vercel.app/

Is there any other issue that i need to look in please do guide me. Thanks alot:)

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the "Network" tab in the browser dev tools, you will see that the HTTP requests the https://saderino-dapp-plnhfmbis-blockeyfi.vercel.app/videos/alienplants.mp4 video file.  This file is not being served correctly. Maybe look at hosting the video differently.

Take a look at this link:
https://vercel.com/support/articles/best-practices-for-hosting-videos-on-vercel-nextjs-mp4-gif